# What jQuery modal popup or lightbox plugin works in IE7, IE8, IE9 Firefox, Chrome, Safari?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, popup, modal-dialog

We're looking to put a popup login window on the screen while dimming the background and disabling mouse clicks to it.

We're using jQuery, and this is a Rails 3 application, and we're looking for a lean plugin.

It's been bafflingly difficult to come up with a framework that supports IE7 and IE8 equally. The other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE9) haven't posed much of a problem.

We'd also like to avoid using background image overlays, if possible, due to lateny concerns. For the same reason we don't want to load the whole effects library, if possible.

Thoughts?

Thanks,

Wolf

Comment: you never expect that your site is compatible for IE9. but planning for future nice !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Colorbox**](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Great. Thanks. We'll give that a try.

Comment: Mark an answer as read mate. You won't get responses without a decent acceptance ratio.

Comment: looks promising gonna try real quick!

Answer (score 0):

I've used ColorBox in the past (and is good), but now I'm using [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) because it's the most flexible and compatible dialog popup.

You can also run it from the Google CDN without even adding the script to your project.

Answer (score -2):

in my opinion

http://fancybox.net/ Fancybox is a good option. it's work well for me. but i never tested in all browser so i can't say that "it's cross browser compatible".